# text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + query + ")", "<b>$1</b>") with GWT

Tags: java, regex, gwt, replaceall

I would like to use replaceAll with GWT more specifically:

```
doSomeGWTStuffWithTheString(text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + query + ")", "<b>$1</b>"));
```

But for some reason it does not run. I imagine I have to use some special library for this.

If you know how to do the above with in GWT please let me know.

I'm using the 2.4 beta version of GWT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.replaceAll()` in GWT client side internally uses Javascript's RegExp implementation. Take a look at the `RegExp` (the wrapper class) [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html). It says:

```
Java-specific constructs in the regular expression syntax 
(e.g. [a-z&&[^bc]], (?<=foo), \A, \Q) work only in the pure Java implementation, 
not the GWT implementation, and are not rejected by either.
```

So it seems that the use of `(?i)` is not supported.

Comment: I think you meant to say the use of `(?i)` (i.e., inline modifiers) is not supported.  Most other uses of `?` (reluctant quantifiers, non-capturing groups, etc.) work the same in JavaScript as they do in Java.

Answer (score 2):

If that's your entire line, you're forgetting to assign the returned string to something. The `replaceAll()` method doesn't implicitly assign the result of the replacement to its `String` object.

Test:

```
String text = "I am trying to match SOMETHING";
String query = "ing";

System.out.println(text);
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + query + ")", "<b>$1</b>");
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
I am trying to match SOMETHING
I am try<b>ing</b> to match SOMETH<b>ING</b>
```

Comment: @Mat Ah. Since I now know that thought doesn't apply, I set up the "Getting Started" GWT application to try this out. It worked as expected in both `client` and `server` code, but I was using GWT 2.3. Do you have the same problem for other versions, or just 2.4 beta? Also, quick sanity check I assume you've verified: does `doSomeGWTStuffWithTheString()` receive the "replaced" string you expect? Thanks.

Comment: @Mat Maybe the part I tried was optimized out because it was static text and thus not converted into JavaScript.